# How does shiny determine dependencies

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

While working on an app, I noticed shiny recalculates an output when it is not necessary (in my opinion), and it seems to depend on the nesting in `reactiveValues`.

## UI:

```
library(shiny)
n <- 5
o <- paste0('o', 1:n)
ui <- fluidPage(
  lapply(o, function(x) textOutput(x)),
  actionButton('a1', 'a1')
)
```

## Server one (recalculating outputs as I would expect):

```
server <- function(input, output){
  rv <- reactiveValues(o1='a', o2='b', o3='c', o4='d', o5='e')
  lapply(o, function(x){
    output[[x]] <- renderText({
      cat('rendering', x, '\n')
      rv[[x]]
    })
  })
  observeEvent(input$a1, {
    rv$o1 <- rnorm(1)
  })
}
```

## Server two (each output is recalculated when clicking button):

```
server <- function(input, output){
  rv <- reactiveValues(
    # difference with server one is that o1-5 are nested in l
    l=list(o1='a', o2='b', o3='c', o4='d', o5='e')
  )
  lapply(o, function(x){
    output[[x]] <- renderText({
      cat('rendering', x, '\n')
      rv$l[[x]]
    })
  })
  observeEvent(input$a1, {
    rv$l$o1 <- rnorm(1)
  })
}
```

When running the app with server one, each time the button is clicked, only `o1` is recalculated (as is printed in the console). However, when running the app with server two, each time the button is clicked, all outputs are recalculated.

I was wondering then how shiny determines dependencies. Can it only distinguish dependencies at the upper level of the `reactiveValues` or is there a way to make the output only depend on a deeper level of `reactiveValues`? In other words, if I need/want a situation as in server two, can I prevent outputs other than `o1` to recalculate when the button is clicked?

Comment: Server two is relying on `rv$l`, which is a single reactive entity. When anything in it changes, everything that looks at `rv$l` (even just one component of it) is triggered. The difference in server one is that each of the list components are *separate* in a reactive sense.

Comment: You might be interested in [reactlog](https://rstudio.github.io/reactlog/articles/reactlog.html).

Comment: @r2evans if I understand you correctly does that mean that only the top level items of `reactiveValues` are considered as separate reactive entities? And so there's no way to have segregated reactive entities at lower levels in the list?

Comment: @ismirsehregal thanks, I came across that one just before I posted this question. It basically confirmed my suspicion (and what r2evans commented), but I figured I can still ask the collective wisdom of Stack Overflow in case there is a way to split dependencies in lower levels of the `reactiveValues` list.

Comment: Think about it: what you're asking for is to make everything, *recursively*, reactive in an R object. That would be both expensive and difficult, with likely side-effects. There are (not great) hacks including storing a copy of each object and comparing components yourself, but these hacks *are flawed/imperfect* and usually indicate a problem.

Comment: This is a good minimal problem in your question, thanks for taking the effort to do that. However, I wonder what your real situation looks like ... often the is an X/Y problem happening, and the actual problem has a different option.

Comment: @r2evans I see your point about a recursive reactive object causing problems, makes sense. I don't think it's an X/Y problem in my case though. I can easily move everything to the upper level of `reactiveValues`. It was just that for organization of the object I figured it'd be neater to have it nested.

Comment: @r2evans If you're willing to write up your comments in an answer, I'd happily accept that, so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `shiny`'s `reactiveValues`, each individual object *as a whole* is the reactive component: if anything within its structure (whether a `vector`, `list`, `data.frame`, etc) changes, then the object as a whole is considered changed (and therefore things will react to it).

To discuss whether it is possible to react to sub-components, thing about this: any object would then be regarded *recursively*. The first example of reacting to the top-level components of a `list`, that's not as bad ... but if the thing to be tracked has many levels (and there is no reason or safeguard preventing that from happening), then every time *something* happens, having `shiny` look deeply at every individual component of the object would be a lot of overhead. It would scale poorly.

For organization purposes, realize that you can have multiple independent `reactiveValues` components. While I doubt it has much if any impact on performance, one could do:

```r
server <- function(input, output){
  rv1 <- reactiveValues(o1='a', o2='b', o3='c')
  rv2 <- reactiveValues(o4='d', o5='e')
  # ...
}
```

And frankly, in some cases this might be better: as much as compactness (one super-huge `reactiveValues` call) might be ever-so-slightly faster (though I still don't know this to be true), one could argue that *readability* directly affects *maintainability* and *troubleshooting*. If the reactive values have a declarative-grouping, it could make a big difference when you (or somebody else) look at your code after a few months of inactivity.